# JPA unrelated entities JSON Root

Tags: json, jackson, objectmapper

I am joining two different entities in JPA and returning a generic object list. How do I add JSON root to both the entities.

Any idea other than creating a DTO  ?

**From:**

```
"data": [
        [
            {
                "name": "Jenny",
                "age": 25,
                 …
            },
            {
                "car": "Honda",
                "year": "2011",
                 ….
            }
        ],
```

**To..**

```
 "data": [
            [
                **User:**
                {
                    "name": "Jenny",
                    "age": 25,
                     …
                },
                **Car:**
                {
                    "car": "Honda",
                    "year": "2011",
                     ….
                }
            ],
```

DAO:

```
@Override
public **List** getPersonCars() {
    String queryText = "select person, car from PersonEntity person, CarEntity car where XXXX";
    return entityManager.createQuery(queryText).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(2).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: The JPA API is nothing at all to do with JSON; it returns Java objects. How you convert them to JSON is for you to firstly define ... and tag your question as that!

Comment: I did tag objectmapper, will remove jpa and incude json ..  Thanks